# Node.js AMQP fanout

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm trying to build a distributed system, I am using [postwait/node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp). Being new to this I find the docs to be very unhelpful.

Now a diagram on my plan:

```
Client -> Gate -> Q -> EatProcessor
                    -> WalkProcessor
                    -> Logger
```

Let us say the client sent `Start Eating`. The `Gate` receives it and adds it to the `Q` the message being about `eating` only the `EatProcessor` should get the message from the `Q`.

So let us say EatProcessor:

```
connection.queue('Q', {autoDelete: false}, function(queue){
        queue.subscribe(function(msg){
            // recv message
        });
    });
```

So how do I:

- Let the Eat Processor only get the eat stuff from the Q
- Let the Walk Processor only get the walk stuff from the Q
- And the Logger will get everything from the Q and just log.

I was reading around and maybe the gate should be a fanout? But I dont see in the docs how to do a fanout.

If a fanout does it mean everyone will get the message? Let us say I didn't write the logger yet, I'll write it in the feature but when I write it I would like to just listen directly to the `Q` and not change any code on the `Gate`.

Comment: I think that you should have a seperate queue for each type and push massages to all of them.

Comment: so a eat q, walk q, and logger q? how would I push messages to all q?

Comment: Yes. Use exchanges (define one and bind multiple queues to it). Read more about that here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

Comment: How would that be in node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so first of all use exchanges. That way you'll be able to publish to more then one queue at the same time. I don't know RabbitMQ with Node.js but I think something like that should work:

```
// define a queue for each type
connection.queue('eat-q', {autoDelete: false}, function(eat_queue) {
    // ...
    connection.queue('walk-q', {autoDelete: false}, function(eat_queue) {
        // ...
        connection.queue('log-q', {autoDelete: false}, function(log_queue) {
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

Then define the exchange and do the binding:

```
connection.exchange('my-exchange', function(exchange) {
    eat_queue.bind('my-exchange', 'eat', function() {
        // ...
    });
    walk_queue.bind('my-exchange', 'walk', function() {
        // ...
    });
    log_queue.bind('my-exchange', 'walk', function() {
        // ...
    });
    log_queue.bind('my-exchange', 'eat', function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Finally you can publish to the exchange:

```
exchange.publish('eat', 'my message', {}, function() {
    // ...
});
```

The message should end up in both `eat-q` and `log-q`.

Note that you should use some kind of flow library here like [caolan's async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [kriskowal's q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) cause you'll end up with lots of callbacks. I prefer the second one.

Comment: I can also just do `var eat_q = conn.queue('eat-q');` or am I wrong? I think we can avoid nested callbacks for this right?

Comment: Documentation says the `conn.queue()` `Returns a reference to a queue`

Comment: The `conn.exchange` too dont need to be a callback it also returns a reference to the exchange object.

Comment: also how about the receiving part? How do i recv msg from eat?

Comment: I see `q = con.queue('eat-q')` then `subscribe`.

Comment: @majidarif 1) Callbacks are used to ensure that queue/exchange is ready and usable. Reference alone is not enough. 2) `q.bind("#")` means simply "bind to everything". RabbitMq substitues `#` with a 0 or more words (it's like a regular expression). Read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Comment: @majidarif 3) The receiveing part is the same as usual. You subscribe to a queue. 4) I advice using callbacks with async.js or q. You might end up with weird issues if you don't do that like publishing to a queue which is not ready yet.